# container class for gnu.mail.providers.nntp.NNTPMessage

Tags: java, sockets, jsp, jsf, facelets

Why does Glassfish shows this facelets error:

```
javax.el.ELException: /foo/client.xhtml @11,74 value="#{messageBean.messages}": javax.mail.MessagingException: Socket closed;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
```

Which I attribute to hitting [leafnode](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/leafnode.8.html) on localhost too frequently and too rapidly.  Glassfish logs below show successful message retrievals from leafnode, but multiple calls to SingletonNNTP.loadMessages().

How can deal with sockets correctly?  Sometimes Leafnode gives desired output, sometimes not.

```
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.1.6 (SNAPSHOT 20111206) for context '/NNTPjsf'
INFO: WEB0671: Loading application [NNTPjsf] at [/NNTPjsf]
INFO: NNTPjsf was successfully deployed in 2,574 milliseconds.
INFO: MessageBean..
INFO: MessageBean..
INFO: MessageBean.getMessages..
INFO: MessageBean.getNNTP..
INFO: MAKING SINGLETON..
INFO: NNTP.loadMessages...
INFO: NNTP.loadMessages...
nntp: <200 Leafnode NNTP Daemon, version 1.11.8 running at localhost (my fqdn: dur.bounceme.net)
nntp: >GROUP comp.lang.java.help
nntp: <211 82 3 84 comp.lang.java.help group selected
nntp: >GROUP comp.lang.java.help
nntp: <211 82 3 84 comp.lang.java.help group selected
nntp: >XHDR Message-ID 3-84
nntp: <221 Message-ID header (from overview) for postings 3-84:
nntp: <3 <afp6m75oi6nli4b6q87s317lkc13g689c2@4ax.com>
nntp: <4 <ed7f31e9-8a19-46c7-9a7c-ad8aabfb9599@x10g2000pbi.googlegroups.com>
nntp: <5 <uA4ar.13560$fj7.13111@newsfe20.iad>
```

The backing bean as so:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.nntp;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.model.DataModel;
import javax.faces.model.ListDataModel;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.mail.Message;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class MessageBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MessageBean.class.getName());
    private static Level level = Level.INFO;
    private DataModel dm = null;

    public MessageBean() {
        logger.log(level, "MessageBean..");
    }

    public List<Message> getMessages() throws Exception {
        logger.log(level, "MessageBean.getMessages..");
        List<Message> messages = getNNTP();
        return messages;
    }

    public DataModel getModel() throws Exception {
        logger.log(level, "MessageBean.getModel..");
        List<Message> messages = getNNTP();
        dm = new ListDataModel(messages);
        return dm;
    }

    private synchronized List<Message> getNNTP() throws Exception {
        logger.log(level, "MessageBean.getNNTP..");
        List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
        SingletonNNTP nntp = SingletonNNTP.INSTANCE;
        messages = nntp.getMessages(false);
        logger.log(level, "MessageBean.getNNTP nntp.size:  {0}", messages.size());
        return messages;
    }
}
```

the Singleton:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.nntp;

import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.mail.*;

public enum SingletonNNTP {

    INSTANCE;
    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SingletonNNTP.class.getName());
    private final Level level = Level.INFO;
    private Properties props = new Properties();
    private List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();

    private SingletonNNTP() {
        out.println("MAKING SINGLETON..");
        props = PropertiesReader.getProps();
        boolean loaded = false;
        try {
            loaded = setMessages(false);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SingletonNNTP.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "FAILED TO LOAD MESSAGES", ex);
        }
    }

    public List<Message> getMessages(boolean debug) throws Exception {
        logger.log(level, "NNTP.getMessages...");
        logMessages();
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(messages);
    }

    private boolean setMessages(boolean debug) throws Exception {
        logger.log(level, "NNTP.loadMessages...");
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        session.setDebug(debug);
        Store store = session.getStore(new URLName(props.getProperty("nntp.host")));
        store.connect();
        Folder root = store.getDefaultFolder();
        Folder folder = root.getFolder(props.getProperty("nntp.group"));
        folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        Message[] msgs = folder.getMessages();
        messages = Arrays.asList(msgs);
        folder.close(false);
        store.close();
        if (debug) {

        }
        return true;
    }

    private void logMessages() throws Exception {
        logger.log(level, "NNTP.logMessages..");
        for (Message m : messages) {
            logger.log(level, String.valueOf(m.getMessageNumber()));
            logger.log(level, m.getSubject());
            logger.log(level, m.getContent().toString());
        }
    }

    private void persistMessages() throws Exception {
        //entities.Messages
    }
}
```

Comment: commenting out folder.close and store.close from SingletonNNTP.getMessages works as a kludge, but the connection should be closed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That message means that you closed the socket and then tried to read from or write to it. You are trying to read Message content after you have closed the connection. You need to save not the Messages themselves but their content, while the connection is open.

Comment: Ok, that's very interesting.  Leafnode functions here as a datastore, should I be persisting the objects through serialization, perhaps, or a RDMS?  I get your point, and absolutely you answered the question, just if you would expand a little about what you mean by "saving" the content.  Thanks for the amazinly quick reply!

Comment: @Thufir Instead of storing a collection of <Message>, you need to define your own message container class that contains Message.getMessageNumber(), Message.getSubject(), Message.getContent(), and whatever else you need; populate it while the connection is still open, i.e. in your `setMessages()` method, and store a collection of that, for use by `logMessages()` and whatever else accesses the messages. This class needs to be a bean if you are accessing it from EL.

Comment: ok, this makes sense and was how I took your answer.  Let me work it a bit (maybe tomorrow) while I keep the message open.  However, I think you've answered it sufficiently, thank you.

Comment: while this does work, I think it's a bit unwieldy.  thank you for the solution, I think I'll try to somehow keep the connection alive.  not sure whether that's a good idea or not, but certainly outside the scope of this question.  Question answered, thank you.

Comment: @Thufir 'Unwieldy' compared to what?

Comment: Keeping the connection alive allows directly passing javax.mail.Message to the backing bean.  I had the wrong approach, in that I thought the connection should be closed after getting the results.  However, the results are only good when the connection is open.  Because, in my case, it's all on localhost, there's no real need to close connections to Leafnode.  At least that's my understanding...?  I mean that compared to having or not having a container class, I prefer not.  Unless that's shortsighted?

Comment: @Thufir It's not about 'unwieldy' or 'shortsighted', it's about what your constraints are. If you can keep the connection open, you don't need a container class. If you can't, you do.